# 最も短いスコープで使用すべきアノテーションは？

Tags: java, java-ee

CDIには`@RequestScoped`アノテーションがありますが、これが最も短いスコープでしょうか？
リクエストどころか、１回のメソッド呼び出しでスコープが終わっても構わない（当然、状態も持たない）処理があるのですが、その場合も`@RequestScoped`を使うものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI実装である[Weldのマニュアル](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.0.Final/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_built_in_scopes)からの引用になりますが、現行存在する**組み込み**のスコープは以下の4種類で、このうち最もスコープが短いものはお考えの通り`@RequestScoped`です。

- `@RequestScoped`
- `@SessionScoped`
- `@ApplicationScoped`
- `@ConversationScoped`

一般的には、質問文に書かれている状況では`@RequestScoped`を使用します。
(ただ、ここは主観的な考えになるのですが、あまりそのようなことが気になる粒度ではInjectionを行わないのでは、とも考えます。)

---

CDIの祖先に当たる JBoss Seam という実装では [`METHOD`](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.1.Final/api/org/jboss/seam/ScopeType.html#METHOD)というスコープタイプが存在していました。
おそらくこれが所望のものだと考えますが、上記の通り現行CDIの組み込みスコープとしては定義されていません。

CDI2.0仕様策定時に`@MethodScoped`というものが検討されていたようです[[参考](http://www.slideshare.net/antoinesd/cdi-20-is-coming/22)]。
[CDI2.0仕様書](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0.EDR2/cdi-spec.html#builtin_scopes)に記載は無いので採用は見送られたのだと思われますが、もしかすると将来導入されるかもしれません。

---

組み込みスコープにこだわらなければ、自前でカスタムスコープを実装することも可能かと思います。
(が、すみません、ここに何かを書けるほど知識を持ち合わせていません。)